# Help decrypting MS-MPPE-Send-Key/MS-MPPE-Recv-Key

Tags: radius

I'm trying to decrypt Ms-MPPE keys received in a Access-Accept message from the Radius server. I'm following RFC2548 in order to do this.

Although the keys are of size 32 octets, the one byte length is always wrong. I used hostapd source for it and also validated against the python script available online. Both are giving consistent results but the length is incorrect. I'm not sure whether the decoded key is correct. I'm wondering whether the shared key needs to be used as it or does it need to be hashed before attempting to use in these functions.

Please share if anybody has a better idea on input for decoding these keys.

Comment: do you own these systems?